# Edit tapped CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview

In my CollectionView the cells have the class `MyCollectionViewCell`:

```
class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var MyImageView: UIImageView!
```

}

I want to set the text of the label to nothing and display an image in the imageView of the cell that is tapped.
The collectionViewController has the following class und code attached:

```
class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

var array:[String] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    array = ["1", "2", "3"]
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell:MyCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    var Label = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel

    Label.text = array[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    println("user tapped on cell number \(indexPath.row)")

    //change ImageView of tapped cell   

}
```

}

How can I edit the tapped cell where I put the comment in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the place of your comment, you can use:

```
let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
cell.myLabel.hidden = true
cell.MyImageView.image = UIImage(named:"...")
```

You'll need to fill in the image name or choose a different method based on where the image is coming from.

Comment: thanks! sadly it says "Could not find member 'hidden'" and "Could not find member 'image'"

Comment: @maidi Hmmm... try adding the type cast that I've added to my answer and let me know if it works.